# Any workaround to the "Could not find prisma-fmt binary" error when installing KeystoneJS?

Tags: docker, prisma, keystonejs, keystone

I'm running into this [issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/discussions/7461) when trying to install KeystoneJS (tried locally with node and npm up to date and in a node:16-alpine docker image).

```
> keystone-app@1.0.0 postinstall
> keystone postinstall

Error: Could not find prisma-fmt binary. Searched in:
- /plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x
- /plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x
- /plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x
- /plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/runtime/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x
    at resolveBinary (/plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/dist/resolveBinary.js:91:9)
    at Object.formatSchema (/plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/dist/engine-commands/formatSchema.js:41:25)
    at getCommittedArtifacts (/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/dist/artifacts-f7bed9de.cjs.dev.js:398:13)
    at Object.validateCommittedArtifacts (/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/dist/artifacts-f7bed9de.cjs.dev.js:417:21)
    at postinstall (/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/scripts/dist/keystone-6-core-scripts.cjs.dev.js:619:5)
```

I have tried so far to update Prisma to the latest version, generate its binary, and place it into the correct folder for keystone. But after that keystone still doesn't run:

```
✨ Starting Keystone
⭐️ Dev Server Starting on http://localhost:5000
⭐️ GraphQL API Starting on http://localhost:5000/api/graphql
✨ Generating GraphQL and Prisma schemas
✨ The database is already in sync with the Prisma schema.
Error: Unknown binary target debian-openssl-3.0.x in generator client.
Possible binaryTargets: darwin, darwin-arm64, debian-openssl-1.0.x, debian-openssl-1.1.x, rhel-openssl-1.0.x, rhel-openssl-1.1.x, linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x, linux-arm64-openssl-1.0.x, linux-arm-openssl-1.1.x, linux-arm-openssl-1.0.x, linux-musl, linux-nixos, windows, freebsd11, freebsd12, openbsd, netbsd, arm, native
    at validateGenerators (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/dist/get-generators/getGenerators.js:318:17)
    at getGenerators (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/dist/get-generators/getGenerators.js:122:3)
    at Object.getGenerator (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@prisma/sdk/dist/get-generators/getGenerators.js:276:22)
    at generatePrismaClient (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/dist/artifacts-f7bed9de.cjs.dev.js:522:21)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Object.generateNodeModulesArtifacts (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/dist/artifacts-f7bed9de.cjs.dev.js:518:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at setupInitialKeystone (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/scripts/dist/keystone-6-core-scripts.cjs.dev.js:416:22)
    at initKeystone (/home/camopy/dev/plur-cms/node_modules/@keystone-6/core/scripts/dist/keystone-6-core-scripts.cjs.dev.js:166:35)
```

Has any of you run into this already and found a workaround?

Or do you have a docker image with keystone 6 working?

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this issue because the `@prisma/client` version doesn't seem to support OpenSSL 3.0.

You need to update to version `3.13.0` atleast. From version `3.13.0` prisma has added support for openssl 3.0.

Here are the release notes which mentions the same: [Release notes](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/3.13.0)

Comment: I have it updated: "@prisma/client": "^3.14.0". generated the correct binary and placed it on the correct keystone folder.

But it still throws an error: "Error: Unknown binary target debian-openssl-3.0.x in generator client."

Comment: @Camopy please did you find a solution to the problem

Comment: @FestusYuma I did not, so I switched to another CMS :/